# What is the A in the mass flow rate formula for solid rocket propellants? How do I get the chamber pressure?

Tags: fuel, solid-fuel, combustion-chamber

I believe the mass flow rate formula for solid rocket motors is:$$\dot{m}=p_pA_br$$ What is $A_b$ in this case. Is it the cross-sectional area of the hole in the grain? What is there is a nozzle? What would the area be then? What if the nozzle was just a smaller hole on top? How would $A_b$ be different in each of these case?

Now for the second part of my question. I believe the formula for r is:$$r=aP_c^n$$ Now my question is if there is way to determine the chamber pressure, $P_c^n$, by simply knowing the design of the solid rocket motor and the fuel mass and density? To be clear, for this I only need to know for simple solid rocket motors where there is just a bunch of fuel packed in a cylinder with a hole down the middle. So really the only variables are the cross-sectional area of the chamber holding the propellant, the cross-sectional area of the hole, the density of the propellant, and the propellant mass. You needn't worry about nozzles for now, but if you do have it. You could include in case I may ask in the future, but that is a long shot.

Comment: Maybe the A is the total interior area of the hole?

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: Where did you get these formulae? Please [edit] the question to include a reference or link to that source. Different sources may use different symbols.

Comment: wherever you are getting these formula from should explain them.  If not, don't use that source.  I am concerned that you actually seem to want to work with rocket engines despite not being able to understand the texts you're using.

Comment: On this [rocketry website](https://www.nakka-rocketry.net/design1.html) they list some formulas for calculating burn area, depending on if only the core is burning, core and ends, core inside and outside, etc. Also I think m in your equation is for gas mass flux, I'm not sure if that directly corresponds to mass flow rate.